# Was the idea behind what would become the Holocaust planned by German elites in that time?

Tags: nazi-germany, jews

Can anyone provide references that point to the Holocaust being motivated not only by Hitler but also by German elites at that time?

Comment: Questions on Nazi's and the Holocause tend to border on argumentation and speculation so I'm not confident this question will last.

Comment: The common incentives to hate a minority are greed, the need to detract the people from their real problems, and the possibility to make money from the pogroms. The Jews were blamed for the financial troubles of the time (Great Depression), disowned, their wealth given to Germans, and some industrialists rich got rich by providing the tools for killing them en mass.

Comment: I am going to close this question because it doesn't really fit into our format. We need to have questions that can be factually answered, rather than implied or suggested through opinion. This question is the type that would generate discussion rather than answers. If you would like to reword it in the form of an answerable question, we can reopen it for you.

Comment: That is a mean way to think in question has to have an answer. Discussions are more profitable than crude answers.

Comment: I believe this is a good, but complex question, that can very well have an answer. It touches the following issues: (1) the widespread of anti-semitism in Germany among the elites, (2) the degree to which the Nazi party acted according to the ideas of the “elites” vs. to which degree it followed an irrational ideology, (3) the (economic) rationale behind the holocaust, i.e. massive use of forced labour, plunder of jewish property, (4) perhaps plans the elites had to shape the post-war German society as they still could (ie. kill future political enemies), (5) the impact on dissent via threat

Comment: and of course, a solid reference stating that this was not Hitler’s personal idea would help to fight the idea that Hitler alone is to blame for all the mess that happened during the Third Reich, as it is often stated by people in order to avoid having to deal with it. Unfortunately, I cannot think of such a reference right now, but I will try to find one.